# How does WhatsApp notifications bypass Doze if it uses XMPP?

Tags: whatsapp

I'm trying to work out how WhatsApp notifications work. First of all, does it use XMPP or FCM messaging? Many online sources say it uses XMPP but the WhatsApp FAQ has hints towards FCM (https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/20887936/?category=5245260 at the very bottom of page it says "it is possible that you are not receiving updates from Google's push notification service.")

If WhatsApp does use XMPP, how does it bypass Doze? Because surely WhatsApp needs FCM high-priority to bypass Doze? Does this mean WhatsApp may use a combination of FCM and XMPP?

Many thanks.

Comment: We are trying to find out the same answers. Recently fcm has become unusable for heavy traffic apps. They have strict quotas now which cannot be increased